# Angular - Interface data to another interface ( few fields )

Tags: angular, interface

1. I have an interface

```
export interface User {
  userName: string;
  creationDate: string;
  modificationDate: string;
  status: number;
  uid: number;
}
```

2. I have another interface UserStatus

```
export interface UserStatus {
  uid: number;
  status: number;
}
```

I just want to keep the data of User in UserStatus ( those that match the names ).
So remove the fields that are not needed like userName etc.

What is the best way to do it please ?

Comment: when you say 'keep data'. are you looking to maintain the data of an instance of `User` object? or are you looking to have the `UserStatus` interface have the same properties as the `User` interface?

Comment: Yes to be able to maintain the data, in fact just a few fields less. Because I need to send the data to a webservice ( with fix layout like UserStatus )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

whenever you get your result for user, use a for in loop to populate a new variable of type UserStatus

[image]

```js
export interface User {
  userName: string;
  creationDate: string;
  modificationDate: string;
  status: number;
  uid: number;
}

export interface UserStatus {
  uid: number;
  status: number;
}

const testUser : User = {

  userName: "RickSanchez",
  creationDate: new Date().toString(),
  modificationDate: new Date().toString(),
  status: 1,
  uid: 123456
}

function GetUser() {

  const user = testUser;
  let userStatus = {} as UserStatus;
  for(let key in user){
    if(key === 'uid')
      userStatus.uid = user[key];

    if(key === 'status')
      userStatus.status = user[key];
  }
  console.log(userStatus)
}

GetUser();
```

Comment: no proplem! Would be grateful for an upvote and a marked as solved if it fixed your issue